# Function exits after executing the first .remove() condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, validation, woocommerce

I am trying to validate my woocommerce checkout form on the frontend only with javascript. The validation executes correctly but the problem is that the function exits after the first .remove() statement.

I want to execute the second, third remove() condition as well after the first remove() condition is executed (I mean all the remove conditions should run).
Can anyone help??
Attaching the code below.

```
function myFunction() { 

  // for name
let n = document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value;
  
  if ( n.length < 3 || n == '' ) {
    var n1 = document.getElementById('billing_first_name'); 
        if(!document.getElementById("sp_billing_first_name_field")){  
         n1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_first_name_field"> This is test</p>');           
    }     
  }

  else {
         document.getElementById('sp_billing_first_name_field').remove() ; 
    
          }


  // Last name
  let n2 = document.getElementById("billing_last_name").value;
  if ( n2.length < 3 || n2 == '' ) {
   var n21 = document.getElementById('billing_last_name');
    if(!document.getElementById("sp_billing_last_name_field")){  
    n21.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="sp-error-notice" id="sp_billing_last_name_field">お名前（姓・名）は必ず入力してください。</p>');  
    }
  }
  else {

    document.getElementById('sp_billing_last_name_field').remove();
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove').
This is the error I am getting

Comment: Indenting code properly to make it readable is a thing. Please indent yours.

Comment: it is correctly indented

Comment: No, it isn't correctly indented.

Comment: Where was the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that you try to remove an element without checking that it exists.

```
document.getElementById('sp_billing_last_name_field').remove();
```

will fail with an error when `sp_billing_last_name_field` does not exist. This is better:

```
let hint = document.getElementById('sp_billing_last_name_field');
if (hint) hint.remove();
```

But you also have code duplication. Let's make a function that can check any input field and show messages:

```js
function checkField(fieldId, condition, message) {
  document.getElementById(fieldId).addEventListener("input", function () {
    let isInvalid = condition(this.value);
    let hint = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (hint && !hint.classList.contains("sp-error-notice")) hint = null;
    if (!hint && isInvalid) {
      this.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="sp-error-notice">' + message + '</p>');
    } else if (hint && !isInvalid) {
      hint.remove();
    }
  });
}

checkField("billing_first_name", v => v.length < 3, "ダメよ");
checkField("billing_last_name", v => v.length < 3, "お名前（姓・名）は必ず入力してください。");
```

```css
p.sp-error-notice {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red; margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div><input id="billing_first_name"></div>
<div><input id="billing_last_name"></div>
```

Comment: @Anurag Since you have tagged your question [jquery], consider it your task to rewrite this code so it uses jQuery.